# Making the source for an image dynamic in javascript

Tags: jquery, image, onclick

See the following html

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>index</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <img src="1.jpg" id="displayimage" alt="" onmousedown="change()">

 <script src="scripts.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the associated JavaScript

```
 imgs=Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg", "13.jpg", "14.jpg", "15.jpg", "16.jpg", "17.jpg", "18.jpg", "19.jpg", "20.jpg", "21.jpg", "22.jpg", "23.jpg", "24.jpg");
 var x=0;

 function change() {
 document.getElementById("displayimage").setAttribute("src", imgs[++x]);
 if (x==23) {
 x=0;
  }
  }
```

I need to make the image source dynamic - is there anyway to have an extension for the image source in the JS, i.e. images1/img[++x] ? This code works just fine as my 24 images are in the same directory as these files, but I have multiple folders images1, images2, images3, etc that eah contain 24 images and I want to be able to display the first set (say, images1/), and then allow the user to click 'next' and the second set (images2/) loads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
imgs=["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg",....];
var x=0;var f=['images1','images2','images3'];//folders array
var j=0;// for folder index
function change() {
   //initially folder is images1
   document.getElementById("displayimage").setAttribute("src", f[j]+'/'+imgs[++x]);
   if (x==23) {
      x=0;
      j++;// increase folder array index for next folder like images2,images3, etc;
   }
}
```

Comment: Great Rohan! That seems to work well! Very much appreciated - i'm completely new to JS. Simon

Comment: Tried to give you reps, but can't even do that! Too new. Apologies.

Comment: @user2576839 No problem if you got the solution, is enough for me.